# Problem with DB container in TestContainers using SpringBootTest

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I have an abstract class BaseIntegrationTest that use TestContainers. The problem is when I'm trying to run a simple DB test like UserRepositoryIntSpec I have an exception, which means that count starts from 114, but not from 1 as expected. Why index not starts from 1? Why every time setup is executed my local db user table is clear, since I expect test to be runned in container with container db usage, so only container table will be cleared. 
It's definetly should be something easy I just missed or didn't understand. I will be appreciate for help.

For migrations I'm using Flyway, for testing Spock.

**Condition not satisfied:**

```
user1.getId() == 1 && user1.getRiskcustomerid() == 1 && user1.getDateCreated() != null
|     |       |    |                                 |
|     114     |    false                             false
|             false
```

**BaseIntegrationTest**

```
@ContextConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = DEFINED_PORT)
@Testcontainers
@Slf4j
abstract class BaseIntegrationTest extends Specification {

protected static PostgreSQLContainer postgres = new PostgreSQLContainer()
        .withDatabaseName("db")
        .withUsername("root")
        .withPassword("root")

def setupSpec() {
    startPostgresIfNeeded()
    ['spring.datasource.url'     : postgres.getJdbcUrl(),
     'spring.datasource.username': postgres.getUsername(),
     'spring.datasource.password': postgres.getPassword()
    ].each { k, v ->
        System.setProperty(k, v)
    }
}

private static void startPostgresIfNeeded() {
    if (!postgres.isRunning()) {
        log.info("[BASE-INTEGRATION-TEST] - Postgres is not started. Running...")
        postgres.start()
    }
}

def cleanupSpec() {
    if (postgres.isRunning()) {
        log.info("[BASE-INTEGRATION-TEST] - Stopping Postgres...")
        postgres.stop()
    }
}
}
```

**UserRepositoryIntSpec**

```
class UserRepositoryIntSpec extends BaseIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository UserRepository

    def setup() {
        UserRepository.deleteAll()
    }

    def "FindAll returns all users correctly"() {
        given:
        List<Integer> friends = [1,2]
        User User1 = User.builder()
                .riskcustomerid(1)
                .possibleids([1000, 1001])
                .preferableid(1000)
                .totalfriendscount(2)
                .friends(friends)
                .build()
        User User2 = User.builder()
                .riskcustomerid(2)
                .possibleids([8000, 8001])
                .preferableid(8000)
                .totalfriendscount(3)
                .friends(friends)
                .build()

        when:
        UserRepository.saveAll([User1, User2])

        then:
        List<User> Users = UserRepository.findAll()
        assert Users.size() == 2
        User user1 = Users.get(0)
        User user2 = Users.get(1)
        assert user1.getId() == 1 && user1.getRiskcustomerid() == 1 && user1.getDateCreated() != null
        assert user2.getId() == 2 && user2.getRiskcustomerid() == 2 && user2.getDateCreated() != null
    }
```

**Application.yml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url:  jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
    username: root
    password: root
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 10000
      leak-detection-threshold: 60000
      validation-timeout: 30000
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1;
      jdbc-url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
      username: root
      password: root
      data-source-properties: stringtype=unspecified
      maximum-pool-size: 16
      max-lifetime: 1800000
      transaction-isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
      pool-name: hikari.local
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  flyway:
    schemas: schema1
    baseline-on-migrate: false
server:
  port: 8080
```

Comment: What has the id to do with a count? Also asserting on the ID with persistent tests is generally a bad IDEA.. If you have multiple tests the sequence has increased more.

Comment: Thats why I have setup block that will be run before every test. But also I dont understand why user table get clear in local db every time, since I expect test to be run in container with newly created db.

Comment: Still what had id to do with count? Removing data doesn’t Reset sequences. Don’t assume that the ID is one, assume that there is one. Although what is the use don’t you trust uibernate? If it us saved it has an id.

Comment: Ok, let's forget about the count. But why the local db is used instead of container one? Why local tables where clear and used, but no the container one? I'm assuming that on the fact, that every time I add info to local db it actually get deleted after the test

Comment: I would say because the `setupSpec` is executed after the application has started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you're using `url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db`. You're literally saying "please run against my local DB" :)

For your use case, I suggest using [JDBC-based containers](https://www.testcontainers.org/usage/database_containers.html#jdbc-url) in Testcontainers. It will start the container automatically and destroy it when you close your last connection to it.

Comment: yeah, exactly what was the problem. Thanks!